# PBI paginated SUM initial opening balance only

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-paginated-reports

I'm trying to recreate a ERP system report within power BI/paginated. However I'm really struggling with calculating the opening balance group totals for this report, as there is a opening balance for each month within the date range, and when I come to the header total I need to sum only the initial opening balances at the beginning of the date range for each fixed asset (the visible output basically). How can this be achieved?

Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

Actual Output [image]

Grouping simply fixedassetnumber at detail and parent group by asset group.

[image]

Can provide data if needed.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some data

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a eureka moment and found the answer myself. In the total header I created an expression `=Sum(IIf(Month(Parameters!FromAssetTransactionDate.Value) = Month(Fields!AssetTransactionDate.Value), Fields!OpeningBalance.Value, 0))`
basically if the transaction date equals falls in same month as my from parameter, this will only total the 'initial opening balance' for the range, logic seems sound.